# Failing to Import Cuda memory into Vulkan

Tags: memory-management, cuda, gpu, interop, vulkan

I'm trying to use the VK_EXT_external_memory_host extension https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VK_EXT_external_memory_host.html. I'm not sure what the difference is between `vk::ExternalMemoryHandleTypeFlagBits::eHostAllocationEXT` and `eHostMappedForeignMemoryEXT` but I've been failing to get either to work. (I'm using VulkanHpp).

```
void* data_ptr = getTorchDataPtr();
uint32_t MEMORY_TYPE_INDEX;

auto EXTERNAL_MEMORY_TYPE = vk::ExternalMemoryHandleTypeFlagBits::eHostAllocationEXT;
// or vk::ExternalMemoryHandleTypeFlagBits::eHostMappedForeignMemoryEXT;

vk::MemoryAllocateInfo memoryAllocateInfo(SIZE_BYTES, MEMORY_TYPE_INDEX);
vk::ImportMemoryHostPointerInfoEXT importMemoryHostPointerInfoEXT(
    MEMORY_FLAG,
    data_ptr);
memoryAllocateInfo.pNext = &importMemoryHostPointerInfoEXT;

vk::raii::DeviceMemory deviceMemory( device, memoryAllocateInfo );
```

I'm getting `Result::eErrorOutOfDeviceMemory` when the constructor of `DeviceMemory` calls `vkAllocateMemory` if `EXTERNAL_MEMORY_TYPE = eHostAllocationEXT` and zeros in the memory if `EXTERNAL_MEMORY_TYPE = eHostMappedForeignMemoryEXT` (I've checked the py/libtorch tensor I'm importing is non-zero, and that my code successfully copies and readbacks a different buffer).

All values of `MEMORY_TYPE_INDEX` produce the same behaviour (except when MEMORY_TYPE_INDEX overflows).

The set bits of the bitmask returned by `getMemoryHostPointerPropertiesEXT` is suppose to give the valid values for `MEMORY_TYPE_INDEX`.

```
auto pointerProperties = device.getMemoryHostPointerPropertiesEXT(
        EXTERNAL_MEMORY_TYPE,
        data_ptr);
std::cout << "memoryTypeBits " << std::bitset<32>(pointerProperties.memoryTypeBits) << std::endl;
}
```

But if `EXTERNAL_MEMORY_TYPE = eHostMappedForeignMemoryEXT` then `vkGetMemoryHostPointerPropertiesEXT` returns `Result::eErrorInitializationFailed`, and if `EXTERNAL_MEMORY_TYPE = eHostAllocationEXT`, then the 8th and 9th bits are set. But this is the same regardless of whether `data_ptr` is a cuda pointer `0x7ffecf400000` or a cpu pointer `0x2be7c80` so I'm feeling something has gone wrong.

I'm also unable to get the extension `VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities` which is required by `VK_KHR_external_memory` which is a requirement of the extension we are using `VK_EXT_external_memory_host`. I'm using vulkan version 1.2.162.0.

The `eErrorOutOfDeviceMemory` is strange as we are not supposed to be allocating any memory, I'd be glad if someone could speculate about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that host memory is cpu memory, thus:

`vk::ExternalMemoryHandleTypeFlagBits::eHostAllocationEXT` wont work because the pointer is to device memory (gpu).

`vk::ExternalMemoryHandleTypeFlagBits::eHostMappedForeignMemoryEXT` wont work because the memory is not mapped by the host (cpu).

Is there anyway to import local device memory into vulkan? does it have to be host mapped?

Probably not https://stackoverflow.com/a/54801938/11998382.

I think the best option, for me, is to map some vulkan memory, and copy the pytorch cpu tensor across. The same data would be uploaded to the gpu twice but this doesn't really matter I suppose.

Comment: Is this really an answer? If so, would you like to accept it so that this question falls off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag, and so that it will be more prominent in search results for future visitors