# how to export an opengles GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES type texture to vulkan texture?

Tags: opengl-es, vulkan

I have source image as a GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES type texture. I want to export the source image to vulkan for rendering, is there any way to achieve this??? need any extensions in opengl and vulkan respectively？ and I have read How to render to OpenGL from Vulkan?at [How to render to OpenGL from Vulkan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907764/how-to-render-to-opengl-from-vulkan), but that is the reverse op of my request. any questions will be appreciated thank you very much.

Comment: External images come from EGL. In Vulkan terms, they're functionally equivalent to swapchain images. But they work in an entirely different API from those, so it's not really reasonable to expect to be able to do that.

Comment: There are only platform-specific ways to do this, so without knowing what platform you're on it's hard to say. On Android, you'd actually want to create an AHardwareBuffer and import that into both EGL/GLES and Vulkan; you can't start with a GL texture and export that.